# How to link a dependency property to a property of a child control of my UserControl

Tags: .net, wpf, dependency-properties

I have a `UserControl` that has a `ListBox` and a `TextBox` (named txt) in it. I want to expose `TextBox.Text` property as dependency property of my control and give it name `Text`. How do I do that? In WinForms, I'd have done that by simply adding a new property to my control class:

```
public string Text
{
    get { return txt.Text; }
    set { txt.Text = value; }
}
```

but this is WPF and I want my Text property to be bindable, hence add it as a dependency property.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone else looking for an answer, the only way I found was to tackle it the other way around, i.e. instead of a dependency property reading the value of the child control, you should let your child control read the value of UserControl's dependency property. This can be done easily through binding. Follow these steps:

1. Give a name to your UserControl. I set Name="ME" in XAML.
2. Set TextBox's Text property to `Text="{Binding ElementName=ME, Path=Text}"`. You could do this through `RelativeSource` too, in which case you don't need to do step 1.
3. Add dependency property `Text` to your UserControl's code if you haven't already done that.

I'll wait for a better answer before marking this one.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you have to do is to create a dependency property for your text property (like here: [Dependeny Properties](http://wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html)). And in the callback you can set/get the text property of your textbox.

Maybe it would be a cleaner/nicer way to create a custom control instead of a usercontrol.

Comment: Can you put up a simple example plz?